# Unsupported GET request when trying to fetch newly uploaded photo

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a Facebook App where the user selects an image that gets uploaded to my App's album for that user. Everything works fine, the picture gets uploaded and posted on the user's wall etc no problems there.

*But*, after the upload I try to fetch the newly uploaded photo using the ID I get as a response from the upload, and this is where I run into problems. FB simply tells me "Unsupported GET request".

Here's the relevant code I have:

```
<?php
# Works perfectly fine
$response = $fb->api('/me/photos', 'post', array(
    'message'   => 'Some message', 
    'source'    => '@' . realpath('path/to/img.jpg')
));

# "Unsupported GET request"... :/ (SOMETIMES ??)
$photo = $fb->api('/' . $response['id']);
```

All the authentication etc obviously works (otherwise I wouldn't be able to upload at all) it's just fetching the photo that does not work.

I'm using the PHP and JS SDK:s simultaneously and I've tried with both. I started with JS and it never worked. However, the PHP call works **sometimes**.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Ok so I skipped fetching the newly created photo and instead simply constructed a URL to it using the ID returned from the upload (all I was after was the photo object's link property anyway - I figured it was more future proof to use instead of constructing your own). *However*, even now when I redirect to http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=ID_GOES_HERE&makeprofile=1 **sometimes** (again :P) Facebook will tell me the "content is not available". After a Ctrl+R, however, it is. This seems to me that FB hasn't finished adding the new content even though my `$fb->api('/me/photos', 'post'...`-call has returned an ID.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, pretty strange because the same thing happen to me.

Work fine and 12 hours ago, completely down. I can't post anymore whereas i've got return id.

When I ask the graph api with the return id I got this :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Just to notice it's happe only when I post image. With link or status everything is fine.

Is FB api in trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Well for me, it was just because the method to post photo seems to change :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos

```
 $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);     
        $picture = "@".realpath('path/to/the/photo');  

        $result = $facebook->api(
        '/fb_id_of_the_page/photos/',
        'post',
        array('access_token' => 'access_token',
                'message' => 'message',
                'source' => $picture
            )
        );
```